# State changes in Redux-Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a simple React App. It allows a user to edit a form to update data in a database. On Submit the page generates an action with the form data. A Redux Saga yields to the action and asynchronously updates the database. This all works.

However in one case the update is slightly more involved. Not only must new data be added but any data deleted on the form must be deleted from the database in a series of API calls. To do this I need to know what has changed (e.g. what has been deleted) rather than just the new state.

How can my saga have access to this information? I could calculate it in the reducer because that has access to the previous state but it is commonly held to be an anti-pattern for the reducer to then dispatch a new action.

Comment: When you say database, does it mean database on the server? Are you updating that when you edit the form ? Any specific reason to do this way?

Comment: Yes, a database on the server accessed via an asynchronous call. It is updated when the form is submitted, not as the form is edited. Is there another way? Perhaps I am coming at this from completely the wrong direction.

Comment: If you dont send the intermediate state of the form to the server , then those dont need to be deleted. Those are only in your local state. You can discard those and only submit the final state of the form. That is what is relevant to the server I suppose.  Perhaps you can add some code on how you are trying to achieve. Also what libraries you are using ? like redux-form etc ?

Comment: I'm not sending intermediate state to the server. The issue is that once the form is submitted I need to know what has changed in that record to delete data that is no longer part of the record. I shall try to put together some simplified code that illustrates what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Sagas have a `select` effect available, which just runs a selector function and returns the extracted state.  You can use this to retrieve the old and new items from the Redux store, and deal with the changes from there:

```
function* handleFormUpdates() {
    const oldItem = yield select(selectOldItem);
    const newItem = yield select(selectNewItem);

    const changes = diffTheItems(oldItem, newItem);

    // make API calls to deal with changes appropriately
}
```

Overall, this is a good reason to keep the "temporary" or "draft" state in Redux, so that you can make use of both the "current" and "draft" values in your logic.

I discussed some related concepts in my blog posts [Practical Redux, Part 7: Form Change Handling, Data Editing, and Feature Reducers](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/) and  [Practical Redux, Part 8: Form Draft Data Management](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-8-form-draft-data-management/)

Comment: I think this is the problem, I don't have the old state in the Redux store. What I was trying to do was decouple the data in the store from the way in which it is written to the database so that in essence I could, if required change the database API without affecting the View. Thanks for the links to your posts, although I may have to read them all to put it in perspective.

Answer (score 2):

> ...any data deleted on the form must
>   be deleted from the database in a series of API calls. To do this I
>   need to know what has changed (e.g. what has been deleted) rather than
>   just the new state.

If I understand correctly you have form state saved in a redux store and you need to know when and what has changed. You could create your own watcher saga:

```
function* watchFormUpdates(){
  while (true) {
    const oldFormState = yield select(selectors.selectFormState);
    const action = yield take (actionTypes.FORM_UPDATE); // wait until action is dispatched
    const newFormState = yield select(selectors.selectFormState); // at this point store has been updated
    // compare oldFormState with newFormState...
    if(oldFormState.hasSubscription && !newFormState.hasSubscription) {
      yield fork(deleteSubscriptionSaga); // start non-blocking worker task
      // or just dispatch action - yield put(actionCreators.deleteSubscription());
    }
  }
}
```